# How to calculate depth coordinate of the 3D rectangle?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, 3d

[image: Rectangle]

I have 3D rectangle, as shown in the image.

Here I know depth distance and x and y coordinates of the one end. Based on these two values I would like calculate coordinates at the other end.

For clear view, I have attached a screen.

Comment: I think you will need some parameters. What type of projection are you using, what is the angle of view, etc?

Comment: even angle is also not known :(

Comment: I guess you're out of luck. If you only know 2D coordinates and you want it to represent 3D you somehow need one dimension of information. As it stands you cannot know the other coordinates if you don't even know the projection type.

Comment: But, do you know the formulas used? You will need to know the relation between x/y/z in 3D and the resulting x/y in 2D. If you know them you could rewrite them to convert 2D to 3D, apply the depth addition and convert back to 2D.

Comment: I have resulting x, y coordinate of front rectangle. but don't no the formula used

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the relation between 2D and 3D (i.e. the projection formulas used) then you can't apply the depth.

That said, if you make the following assumptions:

- the projection type is orthographic
- a depth line is projected as a 45 degrees line
- the length of a 45 degrees line is the same as if it was a normal line

... then you could calculate it with Pythagoras' theorem as follows:

[image: Triangle]

The red lines are equal (in case of a 45 degree line), so:

```
x1 = 100  +  50 * (1 / sqrt(2))
y1 = 50   -  50 * (1 / sqrt(2))
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives right direction, need to found out exact co-ordinates of other end. Any idea how to convert 3D point to 2D

Comment: @flex: The 3D idea is out of scope because you don't have enough information.

Comment: i tried above formula, x1,y1 values are not mapped exactly to the edge,  however coordinates are drawn in exactly in same direction. I have raised another question on this forum, it may give full idea. pls have look at this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267839/how-to-draw-line-in-3d-rectangle-based-on-x-y-and-z